how can I use sklearn-crf suite with documents and not sentences?
I'd like to train my crf model on documents and not on sentences as shown in the documentation https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html).
In this case, I have the following structure :
[
    [   # Document 1
        [('word1', {'feature1': 'value1', 'feature2': 'value2', ...}), ('word2', {'feature1': 'value3', 'feature2': 'value4', ...}), ...],  # Phrase 1
        [('word3', {'feature1': 'value5', 'feature2': 'value6', ...}), ('word4', {'feature1': 'value7', 'feature2': 'value8', ...}), ...],  # Phrase 2
        ...
    ],
    [   # Document 2
        ...
    ],
    ...
]

Unfortunately, I get the following message:
    trainer.append(xseq, yseq)
  File "pycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.pyx", line 312, in pycrfsuite._pycrfsuite.BaseTrainer.append
  File "<stringsource>", line 48, in vector.from_py.__pyx_convert_vector_from_py_std_3a__3a_string
  File "<stringsource>", line 15, in string.from_py.__pyx_convert_string_from_py_std__in_string
TypeError: expected bytes, list found 

I have the impression that crf does not accept such a format. What should I do in this case?
